# How to use API key in google cloud client libraries (python/datastore)?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, datastore

I have a Google Cloud Platform Datstore instance and would like to run queries against it from a Python client.  All of the examples show how to do this given a [service account keyfile](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/libraries):

```
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="/home/user/Downloads/[FILE_NAME].json"
```

However, I plan to run this on a Serverless platform and don't want to include a keyfile with my deployment.  Instead I've setup an [API key](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/api-keys) and given it access to Datastore.

How can I then make `datastore.Client()` aware of this API Key?

```
from google.cloud import datastore
datastore_client = datastore.Client()
```

It takes `credentials` as an optional keyword arg, but I can't figure out how to create the proper credentials object out of an API key.

**As an aside**

I am amenable to other forms of auth if recommended. Basically I want to deploy a web application in Google Cloud Platform - what is the standard way to manage service accounts such that files don't have to be passed around ad-hoc?

Comment: Datastore does not support API Keys. You must use a service account.

Comment: Thanks John.  So does this mean putting a servicekey.json file on the remote box on which I'll run the app?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "remote box". Your code will need to use a service account. If you have no other secure method of storing the service account, then yes you will need to store on the "remote box". If by remote box you mean another Google service, take a look at Google Cloud Secret Manager. https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/identity-security/introducing-google-clouds-secret-manager

Comment: Ok will do that, thanks!  Just to clarify - I was wondering what is the correct way to have the service account injected into my application when it's running on a remote host somewhere.  Locally I just have the file on disk

Comment: Injecting the service account file is generally not the problem. The problem is how and where to store this secret key!